# Access Windows Azure API via Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, azure

I am interested in the best practices to access Windows Azure API from a Silverlight application?  I am pretty sure as an experienced developer it will require me to build a back end web service that silverlight can then use as an interface between Azure API and Silverlight.  But I am concerned with speed and security...For instance I am guessing I can use WCF, but what is the fastest way to get this communication to occur?

Also this is an assumption on my part that a webservice is needed, is there any support from Azure for Silverlight?  I couldn't find anything on Microsoft site about this, only how to host a Silverlight application on your Azure Storage Blob which is not what I am asking...

Thanks!

Comment: Azure has this concept of roles, with a role essentially hosted in a vm instance in Azure. There are web roles (externally reachable, designed for, say, web hosting and service hosting), and worker roles (intended for background tasks, maybe processing a queue of items). This allows you to easily host a Silverlight app and related services.

Comment: You can go check this answer, it give more detail. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026556/431072](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026556/431072)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. You will have to create a web service (wcf is considered best practice) that exposes the methods in the Azure API that you want to access.